# Setting a "No Data" string to Nan in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I've got a ginormous dataframe and in some of the columns I've got a mixture of float64 and strings saying "No Data". Any way of creating an algorithm that searches the dataframe and replaces those "No Data" with Nan?
I'm fairly new to pandas, so any tip is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: You could do it with simple indexing `df.loc[df[my_col] == "No Data", my_col] = np.nan` ?

Comment: But a cleaner way might be to use [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors="coerce"` since the rest of the column contains floats already

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly!!!